# Brotli Decompress Webstreams (in Cloudflare Workers)

Tags: cloudflare-workers, http-compression

I have a bunch of data that I'm storing as files on Cloudflare's R2. I very early on noticed that these data files were approaching a bucket size of terrabytes so applied brotli compression which brought the size down to ~500mb.

I am now trying to expose the data via workers (to apply a filter) and have hit a snag. Cloudflare exposes WebStreams which has [DecompressionStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DecompressionStream/DecompressionStream) which can decompress gzip, but not brotli.

I did convert the stream to gzip ...

```js
let stm = resp.body
  .pipeThrough(new DecompressionStream("gzip"))
  .pipeThrough(ApplyFilter(sDate, eDate))
  .pipeThrough(new CompressionStream("gzip"))
;
```

Gzip is not offering nearly the level of compression I got used to with Brotli.

```
261M   1158172.data    (100%)
2.8M   1158172.data.gz (  1%)
 78K   1158172.data.br (  0.03%)
```

So,

1. Is there a brotli decompress for webstreams products?

   - I've always relied on the browser to just handle this
2. Is there a way I can trick my Worker or R2 into auto decompressing?

   - All the browsers support it. Can I hook into that somehow?
3. Should I just pass the whole thing to the browser to do the work?

   - I was hoping to avoid this because I want the server to control the data exposure
4. Something else I haven't thought of?

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention having tried to convert to Node streams and using node's `zlib.createBrotliDecompress`. Unfortunatly, it [does not appear](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/nodejs/) that Cloudflare supports `zlib` in workers

```
Uncaught Error: No such module "node:zlib".
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a brotli decompress for webstreams products?

There is no support for Brotli in the (de)CompressionStream standard, but you could probably do it with WebAssembly.

> Is there a way I can trick my Worker or R2 into auto decompressing?

Cloudflare will handle on-the-fly decompression itself if the client's `Accept-Encoding` header doesn't indicate support for what is shown on your response's `Content-Encoding` header.

Just return the compressed file as-is, with the appropriate `Content-Encoding` header.

```js
export default {
  async fetch(req, env, ctx) {
    const obj = await env.R2.get('result.br');

    return new Response(obj.body, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Encoding': 'br'
      },
      encodeBody: 'manual'
    });
  },
};
```

```bash
curl https://xxx.xxx.workers.dev/ --header "Accept-Encoding: br" --output - -vvv
< Content-Length:15
< Content-Encoding: br
<binary content>

curl https://xxx.xxx.workers.dev/ --header "Accept-Encoding: identity" -vvv
<no content-length header, due to on-the-fly decompression>
<plain-text content>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not allow me to filter the data on the worker

Comment: There is nothing native to Workers that can handle Brotli, it all happens outside of the runtime - you would need to use a third party library, which is likely going to be WebAssembly.

They might eventually add `node:zlib` to https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/nodejs/, but there's no existing work to implement that which I'm aware of.

Comment: You could try and fetch your R2 assets using https://github.com/mhart/aws4fetch in a Worker (as opposed to using bindings) which might decompress it on-the-fly (so it's plain-text in the Worker), which you can filter and return in the Worker.

Cloudflare will recompress it (if the client's `Accept-Encoding` header indicates support) on the way back to the user. This is all relying on Cloudflare's normal CDN logic, rather than anything Worker specific.

Comment: The payload is only <100KB compressed, at this point I'll probably just let the client deal with the filtering. I'm a little surprised that Brotli is not supported by the web standard decompress stream.

Comment: There's a new compat flag for supporting brotli directly in the workers runtime: [`brotli_content_encoding`](https://github.com/cloudflare/workerd/blob/main/src/workerd/io/compatibility-date.capnp#L322). But it looks like it isn't enabled by default yet and isn't [documented](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/configuration/compatibility-dates/). With the flag on, brotli should be auto-decoded in the same way as gzip.